# Powershell remote execution with php exec function

Tags: php, powershell

I am trying to run a Powershell command on a remote computer with with a php script.

I have no trouble execution local Powershell scripts. For example, I successful executed the following code:

```
exec("Powershell -Command C:\wamp\www\pstest.ps1", $output, $return_var);
```

> Output: "Hello world", Return code: 0

When I execute the following with command prompt I have no issues.

```
Powershell -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.servername.local C:\wamp\www\pstest.ps1
```

> Output: "Hello world", Return code: 0

However, when I try to execute the same code from within my php script it fails.

```
exec("Powershell -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.servername.local C:\wamp\www\pstest.ps1", $output, $return_var);
```

> Output: "", Return code: 1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account that the service is running under has admin rights on that target system. This should be fine if it is a personal project at home. You may have to rethink things if this is on a corporate system.